# When do Gorenstein Stanley-Reisner rings have Du Bois singularities?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

The question is pretty much as in the title. Given a simplicial complex $\Delta$, I can associate a Stanley-Reisner ring. I assume this ring is Gorenstein, when does it have Du Bois singularities?

Motivation: I learned from the opening paragraphs of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.4977.pdf that the cycle of affine planes (a very simple Stanley Reisner ring) has Du Bois singularities. I am coming from the study of mirror symmetry, but the Du Bois condition seems like an important class of singularity and I would like to understand it better.

Answer (score 5):

Stanley-Reisner rings have F-injective type (even F-pure type), so they are DuBois by https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.3298.pdf.